# JavaScript Join inserts comma delimiter when only one item in array

Tags: javascript, split

I'm filtering XHTML classes; when there is only a single class it inserts a comma at the beginning. This makes classes that are hidden to have a value ",hidden" which ends up displaying hidden content. What am I missing? No frameworks please, I never use them.

```
var d = new Array();

for (var i=0;i<c.length;i++)
{
 if (c[i]==c1) {d.push(c2);}
 else if (c[i]==c2) {d.push(c1);}
 else if (c[i]!='') {d.push(c[i]);}
}

d.join(' ');
alert(d);
```

Comment: Um, you are alerting `d` and not `d.join(' ')`. Try alerting `d.length`; I bet it's 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d is still an array after using join().
Store the result of join() in a variable to get the resulting string:

```
joined=d.join(' ');
alert(joined);
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably have an `Array`, of which there is an `undefined`, `null` or empty string as the first member, which is having its `toString()` called somewhere (perhaps implicitly), which calls its `join()` and the default joiner is the comma (`,`), resulting in a string with a comma at the start.

```
>>> [null,'hidden'] + '';
",hidden"
```

Comment: Awesome! Too little time to think. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
if (d.length == 1) {
    alert(d[0].substr(1, d[0].length));
}
```

to clear the first sign.